# What is meaning of “in...day(s), month(s), year(s) and etc?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

What is meaning of “in...day(s), month(s), year(s) and etc?
If I make these sentences below, what would be the meaning of them.
     -In 100 years, people will travel to the Mars easily.
     -In 10 years, people around the world will probably use automatic car.
I have studied about making predictions in English book. Then I am confused about the meaning of in...day(s), month(s), year(s). Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have a look at the definition of "in" in a dictionary - for example, definition #3 [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in). Then explain what exactly do you find confusing.

Comment: "within" is also commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

Here 'in' is a preposition which means *after a particular length of time*. So

> In 100 years, people will travel to the Mars easily.

Means after a century, people will travel to Mars easily.

Another example:

> She learnt to drive in three weeks.